# Branch.io URL testing without deploying App on App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, branch.io

I want to test newly added `addMetadataKey` in branch share link             `[branchUniversalObject addMetadataKey:@"user_name" value:user_name ];` is present in the `params` or not.

If user clicks a link, if he doesn't have an app installed, he'll be redirected to the app store but app store deployed version dabove code yet then **How can i test for new code ?**

I want to check on Xcode stimulator share `addMetadataKey` parameters. I need `addMetadataKey` parameters in some functionality.
Is there any way to do testing without deploying app?

How can I do that?

```
// Branch.IO
Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions isReferrable:YES andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Branch io params  ....    %@ ",params);
    NSString *shareUserName = [params objectForKey:@"user_name"];
    NSLog(@"%@",shareUserName);
    if (!error) {

}}];
```

Comment: what about TestFairy ?

Comment: TestFairy is for app testing i just want to check parameters inside branch share link in stimulator to use referral user name for other functionalities in app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out this link [test a new install before app (with branch-io) is released to the store?](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/issues/246)

In the mean time, unfortunately, here's the test flow:

1. Uninstall the app
2. Click a Branch link with the deep link data you want (here's a couple ways you can create one https://dev.branch.io/link_creation_guide/)
3. Install the app from Xcode with proper Branch key
4. Data will be passed through to initSession callback

Answer (score 12):

Alex from Branch.io here: Branch doesn't know (or care) how the application is installed onto your device. Installing directly from Xcode and using a beta distribution system (TestFlight, Hockey, Fabric, etc.) are treated exactly the same way as going through the App Store.

Here is a flow you can use to test this:

1. Install a build of your app that includes the Branch SDK
2. Generate a link and post it somewhere like iOS Notes
3. Uninstall your app
4. Open the link and let it redirect all the way through to the App Store page
5. Close the App Store
6. Install a build of your app locally (using either Xcode or TestFlight/Fabric/etc.)
7. Open your app
8. The link data will be returned to you, exactly the same way it would be when your app is installed from the App Store by a user.